# Connect USM hard disk to USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, nas

Yesterday I bought [Seagate 2Bay 4 TB NAS business storage](http://m.seagate.com/external-hard-drives/network-storage/business/business-storage-2-bay-nas/).

Seller included [Seagate Backup Plus 1 TB USM drive](http://www.ebuyer.com/642789-seagate-backup-plus-1tb-hard-drive-stbu1000410?gclid=CjgKEAjwtZucBRD77aiiq_v4xnASJABkAg8JxkQvP0TFVhFWG6mg_OVTtoSAD2Wa0TG-oVbsuJbe1_D_BwE).

The USM disk fits nicely in my NAS, but is it possible to use it as external hard drive? It has no USB connector and no additional interface or converter was attached.

Is it possible to get something like USM  to USB adapter?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found something similar here:
http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Datage-USM-USB3-0-HDD-Connector_1148344334.html

but you have to order at minimum 10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cable in amazon: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Seagate-FreeAgent-GoFlex-USB-Cable/dp/B003KGBBPY

Its from another device, but fits perfectly!